# QGIS PROJ custom CRS for only shifting X and Y

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, proj, wgs84

I'm not very fluent with CRS and custom CRS but I'm only want to shift X and Y WGS84/32N coordinates.
For example: with point A(115633.49, 57104.49) of my maps,
in EPGS:32632 would be A(1112126.15, 4590053.01)

So it is necessary false_East:996492.66 and false_Nord:4532948.52 by WGS84/32N paramethers.

In custom QGIS CRS I set:

`PROJCS["NEGIS_S1", GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]], PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"], PARAMETER["False_Easting",1496492.66], PARAMETER["False_Northing",4532948.52], PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0], PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996], PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0], UNIT["Meter",1.0], AUTHORITY["EPSG",99999]]`

but QGIS said me "the definition is not valid"...
But validating is ok and proof is ok

[image]

Comment: "PARAMETER["False_Easting",1496492.66], PARAMETER["False_Northing",4532948.52]" How are you getting these numbers?

Comment: They came from standard WGS84/33N : False easting",500000,
        False northing",0, adding DX and DY foundend in my case study :996492.66 and 4532948.52 ... I wrote wrong... It will be false_e/n = STANDARD VALUE FROM 32632 + DX OR DY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coordinates (1112126.15,4590053.01) are so far east of UTM zone 32N that it lands in zone 33. But even so, check my math:

ΔX: 115633.49-1112126.15=-996492.66

ΔY: 57104.49-4590053.01=-4532948.52

So for your WKT Definition you'd have:

NEGIS_S1 False Easting: 500000 + (-996492.66) = -496492.66

NEGIS_S1 False Northing: 0 + (-4532948.52) = -4532948.52

QGIS is throwing up a red flag probably because the numbers just don't work.

Comment: Thanks, but why it is Original Coordinates - Transformed? I Thought for sure that it was Tranformed - Original. By The way it is true: the point is on 33n zone, but to simplify since the original datum is on 32N (it is a very large DB) i prefered to start with it.